# Drawing samples conditioned to be larger than the previous, until a threshold is hit

Tags: distributions, conditional-probability

Suppose I have some probability density function $f$ and a threshold $t$.

Let $X_0 = 0$

I now recursively draw $X_{i + 1}$ using the distribution defined by $f(x | x \gt X_i)$ until $X_k \gt t$ for some $k$.

What's the name for this sort of process?  What can I say about $\sum_1^k g(X_i)$ for some function $g$?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?  If not, I'm curious what the context is.

Comment: I'm a long way from homework days.  Suppose we are doing something over some unknown period of time, but only have a good idea how to do it is the time period is fixed.  So we choose some distribution, act according to that, until we see that we chose too short a time, so make a selection from what remains, and so on.  When it turns out that this actually stopped at $t$, we incur costs $g$ for each suboptimal choice we made, (and another cost, not accounted for here for when we chose too long a period).

Comment: Fair enough!  That's an interesting problem.

Comment: Your problem is no more general than the specific case where $f$ is the density of a uniform variable defined on the interval $[0,1]$ and $X_0$ is arbitrary, so you might as well focus on that.  Although you don't have a definite question about $g$, it sounds like you might be interested in the [stopping time of a submartingale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)#Submartingales,_supermartingales,_and_relationship_to_harmonic_functions).

Answer (score 1):

As [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber) points out in the comments, your problem can be considered for the uniform distribution without loss of generality, since every continuous random variable is a monotonitc transform of a continuous uniform random variable.  Since a uniform random variable with an imposed condition of a lower-bound is still uniform (over its new conditional range) the problem further simplifies into a problem that can be written as a transformation of an underlying IID sequence of uniform random variables.

It turns out that this problem leads you to some analytically complicated results, relating to the use of the inclusion-exclusion summation form on a set of uniform random variables.  I cannot get a full analytic solution to your problem, but here is substantial progress towards a solution.

---

**Specifying the problem:** Let $U_1, U_2, U_3, ... \sim \text{IID U}(0,1)$ and define the corresponding series of interest $X_0, X_1, X_2, X_3, ...$ by the recursive equations:

$$X_0 = 0 \quad \quad \quad \quad X_{t+1} = X_t + (1-X_t) U_{t+1}.$$

It is easily verified that $X_{t+1} | x_t \sim \text{U}(x_t,1)$, which is the desired conditional distribution in your problem.  It is also notable that the sequence of values of interest is strictly increasing (which is a property we will use in the solution below).  Now, for any argument value $0<t<1$ we define:

$$K(t) \equiv \min \{ n \in \mathbb{N} | X_n > t \}.$$

This is the index for the first value that exceeds the argument threshold.  To solve your problem we need to find the distribution of $K(t)$.  This then allows you to examine the sum you are interested in by applying the law-of-total-probability.

---

**Finding the distribution of $K$:** To find the distribution of interest, we first note that the values of the series of interest follow the [exclusion-inclusion recursive form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) and so they can be written non-recursively as:

$$X_t = \sum_{\mathcal{A} \subseteq \{ 1, ..., t \}} (-1)^{|\mathcal{A}|-1} \prod_{j \in \mathcal{A}} U_j .$$

(The reader is invited to verify that this form satisfies the recursive form specified above.)  Since $X_0 < X_1 < X_2 < X_3 < \cdots$ (i.e., the sequence is strictly increasing) we have:

$$F_K(k) = 1-\mathbb{P}(K(t) > k) = 1-\mathbb{P}(X_k \leqslant t) = 1-\mathbb{P}\Bigg( \sum_{\mathcal{A} \subseteq \{ 1, ..., k \}} (-1)^{|\mathcal{A}|-1} \prod_{j \in \mathcal{A}} U_j \leqslant t \Bigg).$$

This probability is analytically complex, but it is relatively simple to estimate by simulation using $k$ uniform random variables.  You can do this by direct specification of $X_k$ via its non-recursive form.  I am not aware of any known analytical form for this distribution, but perhaps others on this site can supplement this analysis with further insights.  Obviously, once you have the distribution of $K$, you can then obtain some insights into the sum of functions of the first $K$ terms.

---